# Send sms message using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to send message using Ruby on rails?
I am trying to send an SMS message from my Rails app.
Is there an sample project for sms message sending?

Comment: checkout http://www.sitepoint.com/adding-sms-capabilities-to-your-rails-app/

Comment: @ prasad : this one need user sign up ? Is it free or any cost ? Can you explain :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sending sms you need sms smtp server. if you have any then you have to configure it accordingly. Else you can try some api like **twilio** (http://www.twilio.com/). its simple and easy to integrate but have limited free access.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have much time constraints, you may want to try Codecademy's lessons centering around Twilio's SMS functionalities. I learned some from them.
http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/twilio